# How can I show that $uv = 5 + 2 i \sqrt{3}$ implies that either $u$ or $v$ is $1$ or $-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, radicals

How can I show that $uv = 5 + 2 i  \sqrt{3}$ implies that either $u$ or $v$ is $1$ or $-1$? Here $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: there seems to be missing info to me

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Arthur The $\sqrt3$ suggests Eisenstein integers to me...

Comment: $(5+2i\sqrt3)(5-2i\sqrt3)=37$ is prime in $\mathbb Z$

Comment: Eistenstein integers are norm-Euclidean

Comment: what are $u$ and $v$?

Comment: what about taking norms?

Comment: what is the structure of the units of your ring?

Comment: Let $u$ be any nonzero complex number.  Let $v = \frac {5+2i\sqrt 3}u$ then $uv = 5 + 2i\sqrt 3$.  There are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: "@Arthur The 3–√ suggests Eisenstein integers to me... "  Then that *MUST* be stated in the question.  As the question we have no restriction on $u$ or $v$ so the statement is very clearly false.

Comment: Sadly but this is how the question is stated on my homework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rescue this problem, show
a = 5 + 2i$\sqrt 3$ is an irreducible Gausian integer.

If uv = a, then |u||v| = |uv| = |a| = 37.
As 37 is prime either |u| or |v| in {1,-1}.
Thus either u or v in {1,-1,i,-i}.

For example,a = ia(-i).

Comment: I usually call the Gaussian integers $a+bi$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$; $uv$ in this problem is not of that form

Answer (score 0):

Assume to the contrary that both $u,\,v$ are some other nonzero complex numbers. In particular let $u=a+ib$ and $v=x+iy.$ Then we must have $$ax-by+i(ay+bx)=5+2i\sqrt 2.$$ Also, from the relation $|wz|=|w||z|,$ we have that $$(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)=37=1+36=(ax-by)^2+(ay+bx)^2,$$ since the factors are positive and $37$ is prime. It follows that we must have that, for example, $ax-by=5$ and simultaneously, $ax-by=6,$ and now the proof is complete.

Comment: Did you mean $\sqrt3$ when you wrote $\sqrt2$?  And how do you know, for example, we don't have $ax-by=5$ and $ay+bx=\sqrt{11}$?

Comment: Why should $a^2 +b^2, x^2 +y^2, ax-by, ay+bx$ be integers?